# Converting jquery to react - addclass and removeclass functions without toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I am attempting to create 2 grid resize buttons for a gallery list. One is for a smaller grid (.museum-grid) and another for a large grid (.large-grid).

When I click #museum-grid-btn I want to do the following:

- addclass .museum-grid to #gallery-list
- removeclass .large-grid from #gallery-list
- addclass .grid-active to #museum-grid-btn
- removeclass .grid-active from #museum-grid-btn

When I click #large-grid-btn I want to do the opposite:

- addclass .large-grid to #gallery-list
- removeclass .museum-grid from #gallery-list
- addclass .grid-active to #large-grid-btn
- removeclass .grid-active from #museum-grid-btn

I'm doing it this way instead of using toggle bc for interface purposes I felt it would be weird to allow toggling on the grid size button selections. I want to click on a grid size and then if I click on it again the same state stays in place. Only when I click on the other option do I want the grid size to change. This is reflected in the jquery. I am having a hard time figuring out how to translate this to react bc it is not as simple as toggling; although maybe I am overlooking an easier method.

Here is the jquery I have for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       
    $('#museum-grid-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#gallery-list').addclassName("museum-grid");
        $('#gallery-list').removeclassName("large-grid");
        $('#museum-grid-btn').addclassName("grid-active");
        $('#large-grid-btn').removeclassName("grid-active");
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    $('#large-grid-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#gallery-list').addclassName("large-grid");
        $('#gallery-list').removeclassName("museum-grid");
        $('#large-grid-btn').addclassName("grid-active");
        $('#museum-grid-btn').removeclassName("grid-active");
        e.preventDefault();
        });
      
});
```

And the html

```
<body>
    <section id="main"> 
        <div id="the-gallery">
            <div id="search">
                <input type="search" id="gallery-search" name="q" placeholder="#">
                <div id="filter-btn" class="control-btn">
                    <button id="filter-icon"><img src="img/gallery-filter.svg"/></button>
                </div>
                <div id="large-grid-btn" class="control-btn">
                    <button id="large-grid-icon"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i></i></button>
                </div>
                <div id="museum-grid-btn" class="control-btn grid-active">
                    <button id="museum-grid-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <ul id="gallery-list" class="museum-grid">
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00001.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00001</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00002.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00002</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00003.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00003</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00004.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00004</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00005.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00005</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00006.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00006</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00007.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00007</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00008.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00008</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00009.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00009</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/00010.jpg">
                    <div class="listing-title-row">
                        <h2>#00010</h2>
                        <div class="listing-views"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 1.5k</div><div class="listing-likes"><a><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a> 100</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>     
    </section>
</body>
```

- .grid-active changes the style of the selected button to indicate it is selected.
- .museum-grid and .large-grid changes the size of the grid list items

What would be the appropriate way to acive this functionality in a react template? I am familiar with using usestate and making a toggle function onClick but what If I want to do the above? I appreciate and guidance.

Added information:

I am so new to react that I'm not 100% sure if this is a functional or class component. I just want to get it working. I have done some work to get the filter menu to expand and close using a toggle. Here is the code I have for that from my tsx file. Maybe you can tell me which I am using - functional or class components?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
function VisionExplorer() {
  
  // Creating a state for the filter pane.
  const [filterToggled, setFilterToggled] = useState(false);
  const ToggleFilter = ()=>{
    filterToggled ? setFilterToggled(false) : setFilterToggled(true);
  }

<main id="main" className={filterToggled ? "filter-open" : ""}>

<div id="filter-btn" className="control-btn" onClick={ToggleFilter}>
   <button id="filter-icon">
      <img src="/assets/images/gallery-filter.svg" />
   </button>
</div>
```

This bit of code toggles the filter-open class to the main div which I use css to open and close the filter pane. I use the toggle on the filter button. Is this a function or class component?

Comment: Is this for a function component or class component?

Comment: I added some info that should help to answer that. I am still learning so I need to have the work answer some questions for me :)

Comment: function components are a function will start with something similar to `function ComponentName() {` or `const ComponentName = () => {`, while class components are a class and will start with something similar to `class ComponentName extends Component`. There are a few differences between how they work in the react ecosystem but you can achieve the same result with both. You are using a function component.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll have to look up more about class components. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use state to assist with this in React.

I don't know if you are using function components or class components.

Here is an example using a function component:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    // Set up a state variable to control the mode (Normal / Large) of the component.
    // mode will be the value stored for the current render.
    // setMode is a function that lets you update mode.
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('Normal');

    // On large button click handler.
    const onLargeClick = () => {
        // When setMode is called the component will rerender with the new value.
        setMode('Large');
    };

    // On normal button click handler
    const onNormalClick = () => {
        // When setMode is called the component will rerender with the new value.
        setMode('Normal');
    };

    return (
        <>
            { /* Swap size related class name based on mode value */ }
            <div 
                className={mode === 'Large' ? 'classLarge' : 'classNormal'}
            >
                Text
            </div>
            { /* Swap active class name for normal button based on mode value */ }
            <div 
                onClick={onNormalClick}
                className={mode === 'Normal' ? 'classActive' : undefined}
            >
                Normal
            </div>
            { /* Swap active class name for large button based on mode value */ }
            <div 
                onClick={onLargeClick}
                className={mode === 'Large' ? 'classActive' : undefined}
            >
                Large
            </div>
        </>
    )
};
```

NOTE: Instead of using ternary statements for class names you could look at a package like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

Comment: I will look into clsx. This is about my 3rd real day working with react. This is actually going to be in a next.js app